# Can't change my Java .properties file with shell script

Tags: java, shell, properties

I'm looking for a way to execute a shell script that can change my Java .properties files

The .properties file is very simple :

```
WBURL=http://google.com
```

I want that script to change the address of WBURL

I've been looking on the web but i'm lost, everything is very hard ...
Can't someone help me please ?

Thanks

Comment: What OS do you have ?

Comment: It's on a linux ( Xubuntu )

Comment: If shell script is too hard (and normally it shouldn't be for such a simple case) can't you write a short Java tool?

Comment: I must write a shell script because it has to be run before a Jenkins build and it's more easy ( in theory ^^ )

Comment: See there : http://askubuntu.com/questions/20414/find-and-replace-text-within-a-file-using-commands

Comment: Ok ok thank, how to deal with the " / " present in my http:// that are present in the url i want to update ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk -v val="http://localhost" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="} $1 == "WBURL"{$2=val} 1' file

WBURL=http://localhost
```

Or using `sed`:

```
val="http://localhost"

sed -i -E "s~(WBURL=).*~\1$val~" file

cat file
WBURL=http://localhost
```

Comment: thanks for help, with the sed solution i've got an error : \1 not defined in the RE

Comment: Did you use `-E` option as I suggested here?

Comment: Yes i do this : val="http://localhost"       //       
       sed -i -E "s~(WBURL=).*~\1$val~" config.properties     //
   //      cat config.properties
       //   WBURL=http://localhost     ( the // are just to see more clear in the comment )

Comment: The first one pass but when i update my config.properties, nothing is changed

Comment: To save changes to file using awk: `awk -v val="http://localhost" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="} $1 == "WBURL"{$2=val} 1' file > file.tmp && mv file.tmp file`

Comment: My bad, I thought I had already did this. One again thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that this is the **only** entry in the properties file, it would maybe be simplest to recreate it from scratch:

```
echo WBURL=http://localhost >.properties
```